# Eiffel: non-compatible actual argument in feature call

Tags: polymorphism, generic-programming, eiffel

I don't understand why it is so.

- If I say `attached {G}` it works
- If I say nothing which would be the expected behavior for me calling_entity: detachable RELATED_DB_ENTITY should be conform (once attached) to G which is -> DB_ENTITY
- If I say DB_ENTITY it doesn't
- If I say RELATED_DB_ENTITY either does it pass

Why do I have to specify `{G}`???

### SIT_HANDLER

```
class
    SIT_HANDLER[G -> DB_ENTITY create default_create, make_from_db_service, make_from_json end]

feature --

    some_feature
        do
            if attached {G} l_rest_request.calling_entity as l_calling_entity then
                db_service.set_item_prototype (l_calling_entity) -- Complains here!!!!!!!!!!!!
                db_service.load_with_relationships (l_rest_request)
            ...
        end
end -- class
```

### REST_REQUEST

```
class
    REST_REQUEST

feature -- Access
    calling_entity: detachable RELATED_DB_ENTITY -- RELATED_DB_ENTITY inherits DB_ENTITY
...
end -- class
```

### DB_SERVICE

```
class
    DB_SERVICE [G -> DB_ENTITY create default_create, make_from_db_service, make_from_json end]

feature -- Status setting

    item_prototype: G

    set_item_prototype (v: like item_prototype)
        do
            item_prototype := v
        ensure
            item_prototype = v
        end

...
end -- class
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `RELATED_DB_ENTITY` does not conform to the type `G`.

Here is an example why. Suppose there is a class `FOO` that inherits from `DB_ENTITY` and has all required creation procedures. `FOO` and `RELATED_DB_ENTITY` do not conform to each other. For the type `SIT_HANDLER [FOO]`, the argument of the feature `db_service.set_item_prototype` has type `FOO` whereas the type of the expression `l_rest_request.calling_entity` is `RELATED_DB_ENTITY`. It is not allowed to assign an expression of type `RELATED_DB_ENTITY` to the entity of type `FOO`.

Comment: Finally, what I'm trying to do is `set_item_prototype (some_RELATED_DB_ENTITY)` where set_item_prototype whants a G which is a ->DB_ENTITY?!!! why does `some_RELATED_DB_ENTITY` not conform to `DB_ENTITY` as it inherits from?! Sorry, but even after reading you many times I still do not understand. You say that RELATED_DB_ENTITY does not conform to G why if `G -> DB_ENTITY` and `RELATED_DB_ENTITY -> DB_ENTITY`? as far as I understand DB_ENTITY does not conform to RELATED_DB_ENTITY but the reverse yes!?!

Comment: @Pipo `RELATED_DB_ENTITY` does not conform to `G` because `RELATED_DB_ENTITY` does not conform to arbitrary `FOO`.

Comment: When we have X -> Z and Y -> Z, it does not mean that X -> Y.
Here we have:
X = G, Y = RELATED_DB_ENTITY, Z = DB_ENTITY